Can't use function imported from separate file
My app.py contains a call to calculate() in logic.py:
import os
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, request
from logic import calculate

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class calculate (Resource):
    def get(self):
        print("Calculation requested")
        output = calculate()
        print(output)
        return output

api.add_resource(calculate, '/calculate')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

import json
def calculate(input):
  dic = {"aha": "Aha... " + input, "buaha": "Haha!"}
  print("Returning...")
  return json.dumps(dic)

I've noticed several unexpected issues but I can't diagnose it properly (only relying on examples like this, this and this).

The printout in calculate method doesn't happen, as if not executed.
When I pass an actual value to it, I get error about taking no arguments.
The printout in get shows <app.calculate object at 0x0000012D2CDCE540>.

It seems that I somehow get a reference to the function, not the actual function itself. So there's no execution (as it's not invoked), it's not possible to pass data to it and printing it somehow shows it's an address.
What am I missing?

Please give a [mre]. First and most obvious problem - you've shadowed calculate, the import, with calculate, the class.

@jonrsharpe I added the two executing lines to make MRE. As for the shadowing, let me check if I rename the stuff and see what happens.

Yes, as @jonsharpe suggests, I suspect that the error message you are seeing is about the class, not the function definition, and it is Resource()'s  init method that needs the 3 arguments. This is one reason classes typically start with capital letters.

A MRE apart from the unused imports, how you're invoking it, the actual error message (rather than a vague description of it), ...

@rocky Oh, it's such an aggregating discovery... I, coming from C#, are all about happy-camel-case (i.e. the head is upp. But I'm humble before philosophy and conventions of other platforms. And in the material I followed, the class name was sad-camel-cased, so I though, well... that's how they do it with Snake syntax. I'll be more than happy to capitalize the nomenclature. :)

@jonrsharpe I reload the browser on the default port as I execute the default flask run command. As a noob on Python, I was advised not to post it as it's... default. If that advice was flawed, my apologies. The intention was good and I always consider the minimalism of my samples. The error said that calculate takes 0 arguments. Your hunch was correct so the issue is resolved. It was me (unknowingly) shadowing the function with the class. Now, that I understand that, it's obvious what the printout meant. Like I wrote in the initial post: it's something basic due to my ignorance.
